# Xamarin cannot find inherited custom content page

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

When using `views:BasePage.Background` or `views:BasePage.Resources` and I run the project and changed something on XAML, I got an error saying this:

[image]

Code behind code of the said xaml:

[image]

ViewModel code:

[image]

Looking at the said namespace and custom content page that I inherit, I can verify that the class there is existing:

[image]

But when changing those two lines with errors to `ContentPage`, hot reload seems working fine and changes what I see on my emulator. Any solutions? I tried removing the abstract keyword on BasePage class and adding `xmlns:views="clr-namespace:SpellingWiz.Templates.Pages.Base;assembly=SpellingWiz"` in the said XAML but still got the same error.

Comment: Please don't post image of code [ask] - [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

I can't say exactly why `ContentPage.Background` and `ContentPage.Resources` are the correct syntax for the child element markup of an inheriting page/view, but that syntax always works for me in similar scenarios as yours.

Comment: Yeah, its just weird that VS or Xamarin recognizes this as an error. Hot reload is not invoked on XAML if it encountered an error, thus, reducing my productivity. I guess I will be using ContentPage.Background and ContentPage.Resources moving forward.

Comment: But still, it mystifies me though :/